# Using velocity.js as a dependency on jquery with webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, velocity.js

I am having extreme difficulty in integrating velocity.js into my existing webpack framework and getting it to work as a dependency on jquery.

Essentially velocity.js is expecting jquery (or $) to be available on the global object so that it can augment functionality such that the following is possible `$(elem).velocity`. I have tried using the "expose-loader" to expose both `jquery` and `$` to the window but am being met with an error `global is not defined`. Below is an excerpt from my webpack config

```
loaders: [
  { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: "coffee-loader" },
  { test: /\.less$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader" },
  { test: /\jquery\.min\.js/, loader: "expose?jQuery!expose?$" },
  { test: /\velocity\.min\.js/, loader: "expose?Velocity" }
]
```

I have also tried using the non-minified version. This is where the error lies from loading jquery:

```
module.exports = global["jQuery"] = require("-!/.../node_modules/expose-loader/index.js?$!/.../app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js");

/*****************
 ** WEBPACK FOOTER
 ** ./app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js
 ** module id = 6
 ** module chunks = 0
 **/
```

I do not know how the expose-loader works and cannot understand the significance of the above, particularly since I am able to expose velocity.js' `Velocity` to the global window.

As a fallback I am having to `var Velocity = require("velocity")` into my app files and use velocity.js as you would without jquery available i.e.

```
Velocity(document.getElementById("rect"), { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 1000 })
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 parts to getting this working.
First load jQuery into your page as you would generally.  It's a little chunky to try and include jQuery into your webpack bundle.

With the actual require in your code:

```
require("imports?$=jquery!<jQueryModule>")
```

Replace `<jQueryModule>` with the path and/or name of the module you want to load.  `Webpack` will ensure that `$` is properly mapped for it so it can attach as a plugin.  `jQueryModule` can be just a name that you define an alias for in your `webpack` config.  Personally I prefer to use simple names rather than paths - so you can manage the folder context that's searched - but it's your call.

In your `webpack` config, you want to use the `ProvidePlugin` to tell `webpack` that `jQuery` is available:

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    // Automtically detect jQuery and $ as free var in modules
    // and inject the jquery library
    // This is required by many jquery plugins
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    "root.jQuery": "jquery"
 }),
```

When loading this type of code - you import the variable into the namespace of the module you're using - rather than exposing something from the module - hence using imports.